# Blazor JS interop unable to pass arguments to C# method

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to call a C# method from JS in Blazor but unable to pass arguments to it.

The code is as follows:

```
<button class="m-2 btn btn-secondary" @onclick="FindMultiplication">Show Sum</button>
public async Task FindMultiplication()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CallCalculateMultiplication", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), 1, 2);
}

[JSInvokable]
public int CalculateMultiplication(int no1, int no2)
{
    int multiplication = no1 * no2;
    return multiplication;
}
```

JS:

```
function CallCalculateMultiplication(obj, no1, no2) 
{
    var valueR = obj.invokeMethodAsync("CalculateMultiplication", no1, no2);
}
```

The problem happens as `CalculateMultiplication` method of Blazor Component is not called.

I have also noticed that If I don't pass any argument to `CalculateMultiplication` method then it gets called. The below changed code works:

```
[JSInvokable]
public int CalculateMultiplication()
{
    //int multiplication = no1 * no2;
    return 2;
}

function CallCalculateMultiplication(obj, no1, no2) 
{
    var valueR = obj.invokeMethodAsync("CalculateMultiplication");
}
```

Why it is happeening? I have seen that this used to work in Blazor 3.1 as [this Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdj4YOfWH00&t=686s) implements the same thing (check after 10:00 time), but now it does not. So my question is how I should send the argument to instantiate a razor component C# method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I will need to parse the argument values to int when calling C# method with JavaScript. The updated code of the JS function is below:

```
function CallCalculateMultiplication(obj, no1, no2) 
{
    var valueR = obj.invokeMethodAsync("CalculateMultiplication", parseInt(no1), parseInt(no2));
    valueR.then(function (result) {
            // Print the result of the promise
            alert(result.toString());
        });
}
```

Moreover the result is a JavaScript promise which needs to be dealt as shown below:

```
valueR.then(function (result) {
    // Print the result of the promise
    alert(result);
});
```